# Match words in regex, but only if first letter is upper case

Tags: regex, perl

I have a dynamically built up largish regex, e.g shortened text example

```
my $regex = qr/(daisy|john|fred|june)/is;

my $test = 'Later John said blah and JOHN said ignore john .....';

while( $test =~ /($regex)/g ) {
    warn $1;
}

# Shows all 3 matches
```

I would like the regex to match every occurance of 'John' OR 'JOHN' etc, but NOT if the first letter is lower case, e.g 'john' should not match.

I could repeat the regex words when building, like

```
 /(Daisy|DAISY|John|JOHN|Fred|FRED....)/
```

But is there some interesting way of not needing to do that, and the regex only matching if the first letter is a capital ?

I could run a 2nd check outside of the regex after a case insensitive match as a possible solution, and just ignore it if match !~ /[A-Z]/ or something, but I'm interested to know if there is a way within the same regex to add an extra condition ?

Comment: Whilst there usually is, I'd just stick with writing your code in `perl` and not trying to write it in `regex`. The latter is quite powerful, but it's really not all that good for readability.

Comment: honestly, and i'm a regex guy, I think your last proposed solution is the best way. (2nd check outside regex)

Comment: If it's the most intuitive, I will likely go for that thanks, I just wasn't sure if there was some 'easy' method I wasn't aware of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a look ahead for the first letter being uppercase:

```
my $regex = qr/(?=[A-Z])(?i)(daisy|john|fred|june)/s
```

Use the case insensitive flag only after the look ahead.

Comment: Note that this solution leaves you with an unnecessary group #2. Also, `s` modifier is redundant since there is no dot to redefine the behavior of in the pattern.

Comment: Thanks for the help Wiktor, I think this answer is more intuitive for others reading my code later even if it has that side effect, but I feel like I have learnt more from your answer.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew There is only 1 group, not 2. Although the group is unnecessary, I made the minimum change to the original regex to emphasise what needed to be added to make it work.

Answer (score 3):

You may use a case insensitive alternation group (with `(?i:...|...)`) and require the first letter to be an uppercase one with a `(?=\p{Lu})` lookahead where `\p{Lu}` matches an uppercase letter (thus, requiring that the character immediately to the right should be an uppercase letter without consuming it):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my $regex = qr/(?=\p{Lu})(?i:daisy|john|fred|june)/;

my $test = 'Later John said blah and JOHN said ignore john .....';

while( $test =~ /($regex)/g ) {
    say $1;
}
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/GER7qX)

Comment: What does \p{Lu} represent?

Comment: See my explanation at the top of the answer.

Comment: Sorry for reading too quickly. Could you please tell me where this is documented? I'd like to know if it is UTF-8 friendly and what other options of this type exist.

Comment: You may read more about them at [Properties accessible through `\p{}` and `\P{}`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perluniprops.html#Properties-accessible-through-%5cp%7b%7d-and-%5cP%7b%7d).

Comment: Thanks! Nice resource.

Comment: Thanks for this, I will do some reading about \p from your link.